# ESLint how to apply "Use array destructuring"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Let's say I want to do something like this :

```js
let foo = myArray[1];
```

My project being configured with ESLint's AirBnb rules, it throws the following error: "Use array destructuring (prefer-destructuring)".

I managed to solve the issue by doing :

```
let [, foo] = myArray;
```

However, I see two problems : 1. it's ugly (difficult to read in my opinion) and 2. what if I'm trying to access the 20th element of the array, will I have to use 20 commas?

The solution I found is obviously not viable, so is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) could be useful to get the 20'st index

Comment: That is how to apply array destructuring. if you don't like it, either disable or configure the rule generally (see https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) or for that line specifically.

Comment: If you don't like the style recommended by the airbnb rules, don't use them?!

Comment: This is the only rule I don't like in the whole set of rules from AirBnb, so disabling ESLint's AirBnb doesn't make much sense. I also prefer not to deactivate specific rules just for one specific line because I believe that rules exist for a reason, and I posted this question to understand that reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine object literals and arrays to have

```
const {20: foo} = myArray;
```

Here, `20` is a key because arrays are just, in essence, objects with methods.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I see two problems : 1. it's ugly (difficult to read in my opinion) and 2. what if I'm trying to access the 20th element of the array, will I have to use 20 commas?

I agree it's ugly, and yes you'd need 20 commas to access element 20 on its own. If this is something you do once or twice, consider disabling the rule for that line.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring
let foo = myArray[20];
```

If it's something you do often, consider disabling the rule entirely. In your `eslint.rc` file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "prefer-destructuring": "off",
  }
}
```

If turning it completely off is more than you want (say, you want to keep it for objects, but turn it off for arrays), you can add some different set of configs to your eslint.rc. You can see the various configuration options [on this page](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring)